# How to delete faces with only one edge connected to mesh?

Tags: faces, edges

I think this question must have been asked a thousand times before, but after several attempts to find a solution i am sorry to ask it again:
I would like to "**delete faces with only one edge connected to another face**".
Remaining edges and vertices not connected to another face should also be removed.

I can probably rephrase the task to "delete vertices with only two edges connected". I guess that is more or less the same.

Example:
[image]

I assume there is a simple sequence of commands to achieve that, but I am simply too blind to find it.

I am aware that after a first iteration in the example above, deleting the face on the right side will result in another face that has only one connected edge. This can be covered in a next iteration, no worries.

Comment: Verts with 2 linked edges could be on a face that with edge links to 2 or more other faces. _eg_ corners of a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select one of the outermost verts and go to menu *Select -> Select Similar -> Amount of Connecting Edges*.

Verify the selection, then press <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Vertices*.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this perfectly does the job! 
I knew it had to be easy... this is how a bloody noob looks like. 
Anyway: A new world opened up with the idea to use 'similar'.

Comment: You are feeling like I was a month or two ago lol

Answer (score 5):

**Bmesh script.**

[image]

There may be a way via one of the selection items in the UI, however will propose a script solution

**Selecting**

Run over all faces in the edit mesh, and if all face edges, or all but one face edge are boundary select the face.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy import context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for f in bm.faces:
    f.select_set(len([e for e in f.edges if e.is_boundary]) >= len(f.edges) - 1)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

**Deleting**

Similarly, while there are faces, find the "tabs", and if any remove their boundary edges, repeat until can find no more, or all faces removed.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy import context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
while bm.faces:
    faces = [f for f in bm.faces if (len([e for e in f.edges if e.is_boundary]) >= len(f.edges) - 1)]
    if not faces:
        break

    edges = list(set(e for f in faces for e in f.edges if e.is_boundary))
    bmesh.ops.delete(
            bm,
            geom=edges,
            context='EDGES',
            )
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very detailed answer - thank you! I will definitely have a look at Bmesh scripts in Blender at a later point in time (I am capable of programming in general), but for now I prefer the solution provided by @Allen Simpson below for its simplicity. Due to missing reputation my upvote of your answer is not counted right now - will follow up as well.

Comment: NP. The second script reminded me of an early "game of life" pascal code.  Here's a UV to make you a "_citizen_" 8*)  My avatar is first ever blender model circa 2007 your mesh reminds me of it.